# Anaconda Spyder Save / Write Permission Denied on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, anaconda

Issue: Uninstall of Anaconda 32 bit and new install of Anaconda 64 bit on Windows 10 OS. Spyder won't let me write or save to subfolder in "Documents" (Errno 13, permission denied). It will let me do so to Desktop. I am also able to save other files (.xls) to the Documents subfolder. Everything was working perfectly on Anaconda 32 bit before (other than low memory).

Attempted Fix: www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6IU0_QNG_A  (Assign Windows user to take Full Control of C Drive). I also looked at Firewall issues- pretty sure it is not this.

Background: In case it is relevant, I had a very difficult time getting the new install of Aanconda 64 bit to work. Had to try uninstall / install 64 bit version numerous times. It eventually worked when i used Reno for one of the uninstalls.

Help! I just want to code and need to work with my data on a very short timeline. This software issue is causing major frustration and I do not want to reorder and send my entire path reference scheme to the desktop!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. The culprit was, after all, Bitdefender which was blocking python from making changes to files. It failed to notify (or even log under notifications) on the first few occasions but after clearing the log and uninstall/install Anaconda again, the notification worked.

Answer (score -1):

Better yet, there is no need to uninstall/reinstall. You can go in to Bitdefender and under PROTECTION->Application Access(Safe Files) and check off python as an accepted application. This also is a good thing to remember for any application.